# Set default bootstrap date and datetime values at page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I'm using date and datetime functions for my textfields, when I click at textfield it shows the calender and I select date and datetime from calender and my functions are

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    rtl: Metronic.isRTL(),
    autoclose: true,
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    startDate: new Date()
});

$(".datetime-picker").datetimepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    isRTL: Metronic.isRTL(),
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy - hh:ii",
    pickerPosition: (Metronic.isRTL() ? "bottom-right" : "bottom-left")
});
```

What I want is when I load my page the values set by automatically current date and datetime. I search about these functions but cannot set default values of current date and datetime. I also try `defaultdate: new Date() OR defaultdate: '03/09/2015'` but didn't work for me. How could I do this?

I've done this but my programme is not working properly I don't know why is this happening?

Comment: Where would I go to get a list of available events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setDate as shown below, (this code should be on the document ready event)

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    rtl: Metronic.isRTL(),
    autoclose: true,
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Sample from my code:

Display current Date:

```
buildLogDateToTxt.datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            this.fixFocusIE = true;
            this.focus();
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Set previous date:

```
  buildLogDateFromTxt.datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    this.fixFocusIE = true;
                    this.focus();
                }
            }).datepicker("setDate", "-7");
```

Comment: have you added 'date-picker' class into your textbox? I see from your code that you are using two classes, 'datetime-picker' and 'date-picker'. Add them to the appropriate text boxes.

Comment: yes I added the classes in my textfields and use these functions in `$(document).ready(function() {})` and its showing me `[object Object]` after page load. I use first example its easy.

Comment: how to add `datetimepicker` default values.

Comment: all you have to do is, set .datepicker("setDate", "new Date()");

Comment: For datetimepicker, refer this article, http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: There's no default values of current datetime at page load in bootstrap.